# Наложение двух картинок

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, рисование

подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такой алгоритм на pyqt5:

1. Есть картинка
2. Создаем ее прозрачную пустую копию по ee размерам.
3. Рисуем на этой копии линии
4. Накладываем на п.1

Я такое уже делал на с помощью PIL, сейчас решил переписать на pyqt5 (раз уж все равно на нем основная форма) и запутался в этих классах и функциях. Буду очень благодарен за направление куда дальше двигаться)

Результат: [image: Желаемый результат]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Шаги:

- Для рисования используйте [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html)
- Картинки можно загружать в [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) и на них же рисовать
- Цвет текста, при рисовании, настраивается через [QPainter.setPen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setPen-1), а его размер через [QPainter.setFont](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setFont)
- Чтобы картинка была полупрозрачной, если она изначально не полупрозрачная, можно использовать метод [QPainter.setOpacity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setOpacity). Только после рисования картинки нужно вернуть значение `оpacity`

### Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QApplication([])

pixmap_map = QPixmap('map.jpg')
pixmap_transparent = QPixmap('transparent.png')

painter = QPainter(pixmap_map)
painter.save()
painter.setOpacity(0.7)
painter.drawPixmap(300, 300, pixmap_transparent)
painter.restore()

font = painter.font()
font.setPointSize(100)
painter.setFont(font)

painter.setPen(Qt.red)
painter.drawText(50, 150, "ПЛАН_1")


mw = QLabel()
mw.setPixmap(pixmap_map)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

### Результат (масштаб 50%):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Ссылки на картинки ответе:

- **map.jpg**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R7pM.jpg
- **transparent.png**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG9zK.png

Comment: Благодарю, как раз то что было нужно) А то я этот setOpacity и так и так вертел =) Не могли бы вы объяснить почему именно так: setOpacity применяется к painter в который загружен  map.jpg а потом только идет drawPixmap в котором отрисовывается transparent.png?

Comment: setOpacity применяется на все следующие операции, но нужно это было только для рисования картинки с костром, поэтому сначала вызвал save(), чтобы запомнить состояние рисовальщика, а после рисования картинки вызвал restore(), чтобы восстановить состояние. Можно было и по другому сделать, проще, получить текущее значение opacity, поменять на необходимое, а после вернуть на то, что было, но, думаю, лучше не велосипедить :)